Flutter app not update automatically position with geolocator and geocoding
I'm building an app in flutter and in android, and i have an issue since further days, it's not updating automatically the position.
here the logs:
W/Activity(23615): Can request only one set of permissions at a time
I/Geolocator(23615): The grantResults array is empty. This can happen when the user cancels the permission request
Here is the code:
geolocator
    if (serviceEnabled) {
      try {
        Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
         desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);

        final String currentTimeZone = await FlutterTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
        prayerTimeAPI(position.latitude, position.longitude, currentTimeZone);
        getAddress(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        update();

      } catch (e) {
        await prefs.setBool("isLocationDenied", true);
        bool? storedFontSize = prefs.getBool("isLocationDenied");
        if (storedFontSize != null) {
          isLocationDenied.value = storedFontSize;
        }


geocoding
// Get Address Function====>
  getAddress(double lat, double long) async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> addressList = await placemarkFromCoordinates(lat, long);

      final callAddress = addressList.first;
      currentAddress.value = callAddress.locality!;
      update();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Location not found");
    }
  }

ui implementation

    // address
        Expanded(
                child: Text(
             mosqueSettingsController
                                                  .mosqueSettingsApiData!
          .data!
          .automaticPayerTime ==
           true
 ? packagePrayerTimeController
        .currentAddress
           .value
         : mosqueSettingsController
            .mosqueSettingsApiData!
             .data!
               .mosqueAddress
                    .toString(),
                    style: robotoRegular.copyWith(
                   fontSize: Dimensions.FONT_SIZE_DEFAULT,
                                        color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                  ),
                                 ),
                               ),
                            ],
                          ),
                       ],
                  ),

I want the position to update automatically in the ui app but it only works when i click in another function of the app or performing refresh.
I could provide more info if needed. Thanks

Data part, using Geolocator:
First of all, make sure permission is granted:
var permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
if (permission != LocationPermission.always && permission != LocationPermission.whileInUse) {
permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();

Also check accuracy if needed.
Second: You need to make one request before listening:
await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();

Get steam:
Stream<Position> positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(
locationSettings: LocationSettings(timeLimit: Duration(seconds: 5)));

Handle events:
positionStream.listen((position) {...

If it not help, add logger, and make sure problem is on data part, not on ui. If you have ui updating issue, write your ui implementation.

Thanks for your answer ihave changed the code and it does the same thing any advice
